# Ordenar Numeros e temporadas corretamente

Tags: mysql

Seguinte preciso formular um `SELECT`, cuja função seja mostrar em ordem de temporadas os episódios, exemplo `T1E1`, `T1E2`, `T2E1` de forma continua, para a seguinte estrutura :

```
  `eid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `aid` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `hits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numero` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descargas` text,
  `videos` text NOT NULL,
  `estado` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fecha_salida` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `temporada` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL
```

esta retornando desta forma : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32c11b7/2

Comment: `temporada` armazena o número da temporada, ou o que?, e qual campo representa o episódio?

Comment: Da para usar CONCAT para juntar palavras e imprimir com SELECT, mas você deve usar "ORDER BY temporada,episódio" para ordernar, se forem numeros inteiros e não a palavras (varchar)

Comment: No Caso o "numero" representa o episodio, e "temporada", e o numero da mesma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que as colunas `numero` e `temporada` foram declarada como `VARCHAR`, portanto está sendo ordenada alfabeticamente. Para corrigir este problema, declare-a como `INTEGER` ou realize o `ORDER BY` em conjunto com o `CAST` da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `lista_animes_capitulos`
 ORDER BY CAST(`temporada` AS unsigned),
          CAST(`numero` AS unsigned)
```

Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32c11b7/15).

Answer (score 0):

> [MySQL Documentation: ORDER BY Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html)

```
SELECT * FROM `tabela` ORDER BY `temporada`, `numero`;
```

Pode-se também alterar a ordem de cada campo com `ASC` (Menor para maior) e `DESC` (maior para menor), como sugere a documentação.

Comment: ainda não funciona, conforme o test http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32c11b7/6 retorna fora de ordem os numero.

Comment: A estrutura da sua tabela está errada! Altere o seguinte:
    `numero` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `temporada` int(11) DEFAULT NULL

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0c52/1